# Insert after a select fails

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I want to build a netchange and every time I read the new records a new timestamp should be set in a separate record. So every time I read the records I only will get the new ones. But I am not able to do an insert after the read in a stored procedure. I get the error ERROR:  return type mismatch in function declared to return items. The records from the first select is not returned. I cannot de the insert first because then I will have never data.

my procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getitems() RETURNS SETOF items 
AS $$  
  select * 
  from items 
  where insertdate > (select lastread 
                      from lastread 
                      ORDER BY lastread DESC LIMIT 1 );
  INSERT into LASTREAD (LASTREAD) VALUES (current_timestamp);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create a temp table and use it in the function.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_lastread ( lastread TIMESTAMP ) ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getitems() RETURNS
SETOF items AS $$

TRUNCATE TABLE temp_lastread;
INSERT INTO temp_lastread (lastread)
                SELECT lastread
                        FROM lastread
                      ORDER BY lastread DESC LIMIT 1;
INSERT into LASTREAD (LASTREAD) VALUES (current_timestamp);
select *
  from items
  where insertdate > ( select lastread FROM temp_lastread );
$$ LANGUAGE SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the INSERT the first statement and check in the sub-select against `current_timestamp`.

This exploits the fact that `current_timestamp` doesn't advance during a transaction which means that the value for `current_timestamp` in the `insert` statement will exactly be the same as the one used in the sub-select.

You can also simplify your where condition by using a `max()` function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getitems() 
  RETURNS SETOF items 
AS $$  
  INSERT into LASTREAD (LASTREAD) VALUES (current_timestamp);
  select * 
  from items 
  where insertdate > (select max(lastread)
                      from lastread
                      where lastread <> current_timestamp);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

The above would not work if no values are in the `lastread` table. This can be fixed by using `coalesce()` on the `max()` function (something that isn't possible with the `order by limit` approach:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getitems() 
  RETURNS SETOF items 
AS $$  
  INSERT into LASTREAD (LASTREAD) VALUES (current_timestamp);
  select * 
  from items 
  where insertdate > (select coalesce(max(lastread), '-infinity')
                      from lastread
                      where lastread <> current_timestamp);
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/RJA35651

Comment: Thanks for the answer